# Excess Intersection Formula

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm looking at the excess intersection formula, as seen in Fulton's *Intersection Theory*.  What I would like, however, is a similar formula in the case were the spaces involved may be non-orientable.  Presumably this would need to involve Stiefel-Whitney classes and a real excess bundle, but I'm not sure how the formula would change.  Any ideas or references on how to generalize?

Comment: Funny thing: I have to talk in a reading seminar about Ginzburg-Chriss's coverage of the topic, tomorrow in fact.  They call it "Access Intersection Formula", and I always wondered why.  I guess now I know - it's a typo!